# how to select photos from another table using mysql,php

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database that have two tables, users table and photos table.

What i want is to have a connection between the two tables, i want users to be able to update the avatar field  in users table with the photos they uploaded to photos table. each time they upload a photo the avatar field is update with the new photo, i know about the foreign key in mysql but  am not perfect in this.

Can you tell me if this is the best way to implement such functionality on my site. and please don't be offended if my syntax isn't perfect.

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `username` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `age` bigint(200 NOT NULL,
  `gender` VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
  `avatar` tex NOT NULL,
  `signup_date` int(10) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

then i have another table that contains all photos uploaded by users this is the structure

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `photos` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `location` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `caption` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=5 ;
```

Comment: You have a history of off-topic or downvoted questions and are at risk of losing your question-asking privileges. [You should read this before you post your next one](http://s.tk/onhold).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you have to create connection between these two tables, add column user_id in **photos** table.

```
CREATE TABLE
IF NOT EXISTS photos (
    id INT (11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    location VARCHAR (100) NOT NULL,
    caption VARCHAR (100) NOT NULL,
    user_id int(11) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
) ENGINE = MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET = latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT = 5;
```

Then change the structure of your users table, you have to store avatar as int with photo id.
Change avatar from varchar to integer value.

```
CREATE TABLE users (
    id BIGINT (20) NOT NULL,
    username VARCHAR (255) NOT NULL,
    PASSWORD VARCHAR (255) NOT NULL,
    email VARCHAR (255) NOT NULL,
    age BIGINT (200) NOT NULL,
    gender VARCHAR (10) NOT NULL,
    avatar INT(10) NOT NULL,
    signup_date INT (10) NOT NULL
    ) ENGINE = MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET = utf8;
```

Then when user will add data into photos table just write user_id and then you will have ability to get all users photos with MySQL query:

```
SELECT * FROM `photos` WHERE user_id={your_user_id}
```

Then you will choose id of one photo that you want to make avatar and will update **users** table column named avatar with photo **id** *(photos.id)*

Comment: if i understand how you mean sir,  i shout add the user id into photos table in user_id column each time a user add data to **photos** table? right?

Comment: Yes. You have to write into **photos.user_id** column data each time user add photo.

Comment: Sorry to interfere in middle. Suppose, I'm currently logged-in user and wanted to change my profile photo. So, whether it will update or create a new row @RuslanMusayev ?

Comment: butnow  am not even able to add values to the photos table

Comment: thanks but no value get inserted into user_id column here is the code i ran,  and i have created the field    `if(mysql_query('INSERT INTO photos (id,location,caption,user_id) VALUES ('.$id.',"'.$location.'","'.$caption.'",'.$SESSION['userid'].')"));
   header("location: indexupload.php");`

Comment: thanks for the time, i have figure that out, each time a user upload a photo the user id is added to the user_id column in photos table, and i also use get to get the photo id and update the avatar column in users table when an image is clicked, but the real images is not yet showing up. i don't really know how to display the image itself in the profile.php file

Comment: Show the php and the query that you use to get the avatar

Answer (score 0):

I think the first thing you would need to do is add a user_id column to your photos table, this will act as a foreign key so you can find all the photos uploaded by a certain user. After you do that then you can use something like the following to get all the photos uploaded by a user

```
SELECT * FROM `photos` WHERE `user_id` = <user_id>
```

Comment: thanks for taking the time to help me i have modified my tables, but the problem now is, am unable to insert user id into photo table.